# Is this proof by induction that $|\Bbb Q^n|=\aleph_0$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, induction, cardinals

Is this proof by induction that $|\Bbb Q^n|=\aleph_0$  correct?

Suppose I know that $|\Bbb Q|=|\Bbb N|=|\Bbb N^2|=\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0$.

Proof:

Suppose $|\Bbb Q^n|=\aleph_0$, then  $|\Bbb Q^{n+1}|=|\Bbb Q^{n}\times\Bbb Q|= |\Bbb Q^{n}|\cdot|\Bbb Q|=\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0 {}_{\square}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. In fact, your argument is valid for any set $X$ with $|X| = \aleph_0$, it doesn't have to be $\Bbb Q$. The only possible worries there would be knowing that $|\Bbb Q| = \aleph_0$ and that $\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0  = \aleph_0$, but you said you have this results already, though. Good job.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add this in the question when I asked this, is this result also true for $|\prod_{i\in A}X|$ when $|X|= |A|=\aleph_0$?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: No, it's not true. $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb N=\Bbb{N^N}$ and it is uncountable.

Comment: What? How come?

Comment: Nevermind. I read $\prod$ and answered thinking in $\bigcup $. Crap.

Comment: One last question, is my proof correct for any set $Y$ with $|Y|=\kappa$ for $\kappa$ any infinite cardinal?